# How does data in database assign to array at different activity?

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-sqlite

My project's purpose is that i want to build a vocabulary card. Application will give you a English word and there will be 4 Turkish words (1 word is true word. `Ex : hello= merhaba`)below of English word .You will guess the true one.I will do that with using `array`. Am I wrong or Do you want to give me an advice?
I have been developing a little project. I want to use data in database in different activity. My data is like that in database :

```
ID  word   word_tr

1   hello  merhaba

2   hi     selam
```

....

I want assin data to array at diffrent activity(WordsActivity)

array1

hello

hi

...

array2

merhaba

selam
...

Here my code :

```
package de.murattekinlive.pwords;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class DataBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DBWORDS";
private static final String TABLE_NAME  = "WTABLE";
private static final String ID  ="ID";
private static final String WORD   = "WORD";
private static final String WORD_TR1 = "TURKCE_1";


public DataBase(Context context){
    super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
}

public DataBase(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_DBTABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + ID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +WORD+
            " TEXT," +WORD_TR1+" TEXT" + "  )";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_DBTABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    String TABLE_DELETE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME ;
    db.execSQL(TABLE_DELETE);
    onCreate(db);

}

    public long addRecord(Words words){
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(WORD,words.getWORD());
    contentValues.put(WORD_TR1,words.getTR1());
    long status = sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
    sqLiteDatabase.close();
    return status;
}
    public List<Words> allRecords(){
    List<Words> wordsList = new ArrayList<>();
    String sql_query = "SELECT *FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase =this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor =sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(sql_query,null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        Words words =null;
        do{
            words = new Words();
            words.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
            words.setWORD(cursor.getString(1));
            words.setTR1(cursor.getString(2));
            wordsList.add(words);
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return wordsList;
}

public String getRandomQuote(){
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1",new String[]
            {WORD,WORD_TR1},null,null,null,null,null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        return
          cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(WORD))+
         cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(WORD_TR1));

    }
    else
        return "nothing";
}

}
```

My wordActivity ( I want to do all my task with data)

```
package de.murattekinlive.pwords;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class WordsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView textView;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_words);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String random = intent.getStringExtra("random"); // this is just test...
    textView.setText("Number : " + random);


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I have understood the question, but if you want two arrays with every word in your database just call the `allRecords()` method in your activity, then scan the list to crate the two separate arrays `eng` and `turk`.

Then randomly pick 4 integers (say `0,1,2,3`), and access to those positions to set the text in your textViews (use one of them to retrieve the english word too).

Let me know if I didn't understand your request!

Comment: I think you understood exactly,but how can I seperate list to two array ?if I do , the remainder looks like  very easy.

Comment: @MuratTekin create two `ArrayList`, iterate over the List<Word> (`for`, `while` loops or `list.iterator()`) , use the getter methods from your `Word` class and simply add the two values to the lists. Or use simple arrays, it's the same: you know the size they should have from `list.size()`
It's very basic here! 

My concern is that you want to have the whole database in memory! you should consider other approaches...